# How to unhide Silverlight WCF BeginXXXX and EndXXXX service calls

Tags: silverlight, system.reactive

I have been learning about RX and Silverlight and found a blog post showing how to implement a silverlight wcf service using the Observable.FromAsyncPattern in Rx. In the blog post it has a note to Silverlight developers...

> **An important note for Silverlight!**
>   *Silverlight’s web service generated client code does something a bit
>   annoying – it hides away the BeginXXXX/EndXXXX calls, presumably to
>   make the Intellisense cleaner. However, they’re not gone, the way you
>   can get them back is by casting the MyCoolServiceClient object to its
>   underlying interface (i.e. the LanguageServiceClient object has a
>   generated ILanguageServiceClient interface that it implements)*

[See entire blog post here](http://blog.paulbetts.org/index.php/2010/09/26/calling-web-services-in-silverlight-using-reactivexaml/)

While I can see that the BeginXXX and EndXXX methods are definitely hidden for my service, I am unsure of what he means when he says that you need to cast the ServiceClient to the interface.

If I have generated an instace of the Service1Client e.g.

```
    Service1Client scClient = new Service1Client();
```

How would I cast it? I have tried...

```
((IService1Client) scClient)
```

But to no avail... any suggestions much appreciated.

Comment: I give this question an upvote!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will find there is an interface that simply has the name `Service1` and that the `Service1Client` implements that interface.  Yes I know thats weird but there is no syntax rule that states that all interface types begin with the letter "I".  So change your code to:-

```
 Service1 scClient = new Service1Client();
```

Then work with `Service1` which has the simpler Begin/End async pattern.  Just be careful because the callback passed to Begin will not be executed on the UI thread.

Comment: I think you meant IService1 scClient = new Service1Client(); and then working with the scClient instance.

Comment: @Jim: No I meant `Service1`.  If you create WCF service called `Service1` in the web project then the `Microsoft.Silverlight.ServiceReference` will auto-generate into your silverlight project an interface called `Service1` that lists all the methods marked with `OperationContract` in terms of Begin/End pairs.  It then creates a whole bunch of other classes one of which is the `Service1Client` which implements `Service1`.  There is no prefixing of the interface with the letter "I" in this case.

Answer (score 1):

It means that the generated code includes types that [*explicitly implement*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173157.aspx) interfaces.  There are many reasons for doing this; I'm not sure what the architectural considerations are here, as I have never done what you are doing.

You should inspect your `Service1Client` to see if it implements a generated interface that contains these Begin/End methods.  If it does, *that* is the interface you must cast the service client type to.  If not, perhaps things have changed since a year ago.